# Restart CSS3 Animation without javascript?

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

Is it possible to "restart" a keyframe animation after it's stops with the same animation delay time again?

```css
@keyframes scale {
50% { transform: scale(1.2); }
100% { transform: scale(1); }
}

.animated-btn {
animation: scale ease-in 1;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
animation-duration: .6s;
animation-delay: 11.8s;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn btn__arrow animated-btn">
Aniamted Button
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to set a delay before each animation, but you can set a delay inside the animation. Just let the animation do nothing for a while until you reach a certain percentage.

Here's the updated code.

```
@keyFrames scale {
    90% {
        transform: scale(1)
    }
    95% {
        transform: scale(1.3)
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.animated-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    animation: scale ease-in 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 12.4s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    /* Or the shorthand:
    animation: scale 1.4s 0s infinite ease-in forwards;
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just need to use [the animation-iteration-count property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-iteration-count.asp).
You can set its value to *infinite*.

Comment: thats right - but then the animation is playing all the time. I need that the animation has again the same delay time and then play again